# Webcam capture software

Tags: video, webcam

I need some software to capture video from my Logitech webcam.
Before (years ago) I used VirtualDub but with this new camera VirtualDub says I have no compatible video source.

Is there something in Adobe CS5 that can capture video from a webcam? If no, is there some other (preferably freeware) software that can do this?

I tried searching but I can't seem to find anything useful, it's either desktop capture or doesn't work properly.

Logitech software that came with the cam is of course craptastic.

Comment: Are you using a different OS now than you used to?

Comment: yeah, I used XP before, now I'm using Windows 7. And yeah, sorry for forgetting to include my OS.

Answer (score 0):

That it worked in XP but not in 7 is what I expected.

What you’ll need to do is to get the latest, Windows 7 drivers for your webcam. Hopefully the manufacturer has provided new, Windows 7-specific drivers that supports TWAIN or VFW, otherwise Windows 7 probably can’t recognize it as a compatible capture device.

Check to see if your webcam is [compatible with Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/Browse.aspx?type=Hardware&category=Cameras%20&%20Photo&subcategory=Webcams)—make sure to check the right architecture (32/64-bit). If it is, there should be a link to the latest drivers on the page.

Comment: If the desired resolution is higher than what is physically available, then it won’t won’t interpolate, it will *extrapolate* (or more accurately, scale/stretch).

Comment: Well if the field of view is the same but it consists of more pixels is it interpolation or extrapolation?  It wouldn't invent new pixels outside FOV but estimate the pixels (data points) between top and bottom edges of FOV. That's interpolation isn't it? I'm not sure how a camera sensor works so I don't know. In any case it's not doing that either, rather the stated camera specs seem to be incorrect for some reason, maybe it's not getting all 30 FPS that it does on 1280x720 (there is the small occasional stutter) so maybe that's why the resolution was limited by Logitech software.

Comment: The maximum refresh-rate and resolution are indeed indirectly-proportional. Check the manual, it should say what the maximum res and refreshes are; maybe it can do that res at 25fps but 30 at a lower one.